# NASM Assembly - Changing a character in a string at user-chosen index

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

So my last post was pretty confusing to read, so I wanted to re-upload it to make it much more clear.

Basically, I have a string that is 9 characters long, and I want to have the user be able to choose an index to change to the character "X"

I know how to change an element's value by simply hard-coding in the index desired

```
; Changes index 1's value to X
mov    eax, board          ;board is the 9 character-long string
mov    byte[eax+1], 'X'
```

What I want to know is how I can change the statement above so that instead it inserts 'X' into the index specified by the user.

Here is what I've tried so far

```
section .data
     board           db      0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20 ;Fills the array of size 9 with Spaces
     board_len       equ     $ - board


section .bss
     element         resb    2   ;Reserves 2 bytes for user input. x1 for the number and x1 for the line feed

section .text
     global _start

_start

     ; Prompt user for input
     mov    ecx, user_prompt
     mov    edx, user_prompt_len
     call   s_print

     ;Take in user input
     mov    ecx, element
     mov    edx, 2

     call   read_int

     ; convert string to integer
     mov     eax, [element]
     sub     eax, '0'
     mov     [element], eax

     ; Insert 'X' into the index specified
     mov     ebx, [element]
     mov     eax, board
     mov     byte[board+ebx], 'X'

     ;Print out board
     mov     ecx, board
     mov     edx, board_len

     ;Exit program
     mov eax, 1
     int 0x80

s_print:
    ;; Prints message placed in ECX
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     eax, 4
    int     0x80

    ret

read_int:
    mov     ebx, 0
    mov     eax, 3

    int     0x80


    ret
```

Comment: Your text input is only 1 digit, you need to zero the other three bytes. E.g. replace `mov eax, [element]` with `movzx  eax, byte [element]`. PS: if you need to fix something in your question use the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46984940/edit).

Comment: `mov     eax, [element]` will load 4 bytes of memory, because `eax` is 32 bit register (32 bits = 4 bytes). If you did enter `'0'` character, then the memory contains (all following values hex) `30 0A ?? ??`, so you load into `eax` value `0x????0A30` and then subtract `30` from it receiving value `0x????0A00`, store that back, and use that to address `board`, writing the `'X'` who knows where. ... btw, it should be obvious in debugger, that the `eax` after `sub` doesn't contain the entered value...

Comment: @jester Thank you very much for the help! Seems to be working as intended now. And I will do that in the future, thanks!